# Unable to broadcast raw transaction

Tags: raw-transaction

I am a real beginner and am having trouble with signing this P2sh code:

```
020000000190001f2feb1d5f282f7e15f75259db6200bbdde6498442c7ae571ce4e9f595bd010000006a47304402205f49f55952d189148d570f23e6eb623b65631bdbf88a894c4f314d51a518c65602201bd88c35ebbe52b5dd00c482f4f47211436fe40447c230ebb22ee07f3437a5af0121031a4aa9b7fb5f97d7a6443d72e5420cebd50b2b6986abf3fd5be54e597ee334ddfeffffff026edae88c3c0000001976a9140115aef14ab7459df7e8892bcbfaf4d03501e9fa88ac6bf50904000000001976a914c1d3b9ab95f4a100f8b0e8daa11c01bbe4179ecb88ac1b211300
{
  "txid": "ae3ebf9b4216b2669fca8dc9091903b242cccb345f44883633ba7d7377347995",
  "hash": "ae3ebf9b4216b2669fca8dc9091903b242cccb345f44883633ba7d7377347995",
  "version": 2,
  "size": 225,
  "vsize": 225,
  "locktime": 1253659,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "bd95f5e9e41c57aec7428449e6ddbb0062db5952f7157e2f285f1deb2f1f0090",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "304402205f49f55952d189148d570f23e6eb623b65631bdbf88a894c4f314d51a518c65602201bd88c35ebbe52b5dd00c482f4f47211436fe40447c230ebb22ee07f3437a5af[ALL] 031a4aa9b7fb5f97d7a6443d72e5420cebd50b2b6986abf3fd5be54e597ee334dd",
        "hex": "47304402205f49f55952d189148d570f23e6eb623b65631bdbf88a894c4f314d51a518c65602201bd88c35ebbe52b5dd00c482f4f47211436fe40447c230ebb22ee07f3437a5af0121031a4aa9b7fb5f97d7a6443d72e5420cebd50b2b6986abf3fd5be54e597ee334dd"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967294
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 2600.62108270,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 0115aef14ab7459df7e8892bcbfaf4d03501e9fa OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a9140115aef14ab7459df7e8892bcbfaf4d03501e9fa88ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "16jenAh8U7g3epf7YU1Mmmxf1uieymWp7"
        ]
      }
    }, 
    {
      "value": 0.67761515,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 c1d3b9ab95f4a100f8b0e8daa11c01bbe4179ecb OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a914c1d3b9ab95f4a100f8b0e8daa11c01bbe4179ecb88ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "1Jfs3xHhPBeRThAo9kcsXiGnAVwHpa1tiA"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I can get it to 'true' with creatrawtransaction and signrawtransaction - but it is still lacking inputs when I try to sendrawtransaction to the network.

Any advice? The problem seems to be in the Witness script and I am clueless as to how to resolve it.

Comment: This transaction has nothing to do with witnesses. There is no witness script here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using the main Bitcoin network but the transaction you are spending from does not exist on mainnet. It only exists on the test network. You need to restart your node in testnet mode in order for it to work.

Comment: Thanks. The mystery is that the data in this transaction turned up in both my testnet and mainnet accounts. I don't  know how it got scrambled/crossed over but it effectively formatted  the addresses properly on each side. Very weird.